# TextBox does not display any text in silverlight

Tags: css, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am displaying the text in a textbox and sometimes it does not display the text at all.
The richtexteditor is saving the text to the database and whenever the richtexteditor  saves the text with Typography manner then the text wont show up otherwise it does. I cant understand why is that. Its just an observation. i am not 100% sure thats the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have no idea how can I help you without the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the richtextbox saves it in the Typography manner then it wont display the text in the textbox if it is 4.x.x versions of the silverlight. If it is  5.x.x versions it displays just fine. I just upgraded the silverlight and it started working fine.